# Extend the tangent bundle on a modular curve to its compactified curve, with a Hermitian metric singular at cusps

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, characteristic-classes, line-bundles

The brief setting of the problem is the following. Suppose we are given the Poincare metric on the open modular curve, and the metric is singular at cusps. The Chern form of the tangent bundle defined by the metric, if we view it as a current, has finite integrals on the compactified modular curve. According to the paper I read, with this metric, the tangent bundle has a canonical extension to the compactified curve. Does that mean I need to find a line bundle with the same Chern class as the current previously defined on the compact curve?

Let $\Gamma = \Gamma(N)$, $X_{\Gamma}^0$ be the open modular curve defined by $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is the upper half plane, $X_{\Gamma}$ be the compactified modular curve at cusps. We have the Poincar'e metric
$$\frac{1}{y^2}d\tau \wedge d\bar{\tau}$$
on the upper half plane. Using the covering map $\tau\mapsto e^{i\tau}$ (or $\tau\mapsto e^{\frac{2\pi i\tau}{N}}$, no matter which is used, the form of metric written done is the same), the cusp at infinity has a nbd which is biholomorphic to a unit disk. Then on the punctured unit disk, and the tangent bundle of $X_\Gamma$ has a singular Hermitian metric descending from the Poincar'e metric. Let $w=e^{iz}$ be the coordinate at infinity, the metric is
$$\frac{1}{|w|^2(\log |w|)^2} dw \wedge d\bar{w}.$$
Computing the Chern form of tangent bundle, near infinity:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi} \bar{\partial} \partial \log (\frac{1}{|w|^2 (\log |w|)^2}) & = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi} \partial \bar{\partial} \log(|w|^2) + \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi} \partial \bar{\partial} \log (\log |w|)^2
\end{align*}
The first term on the RHS, viewed as a current, by thr Poincar'e-Lelong equation, it is equal to the evaluation current at infinity with multiplicity $+1$, and the second has finite integration for forms supported near infinity.
Then define $$\omega := c_1(T_{X_{\Gamma}^0}),$$ viewed as a current, is well-defined on the compactified modular curve $X_{\Gamma}$. I wonder how to find a line bundle, whose first Chern class has the same cohomology class as $\omega$? The paper I read says that the extension should be $T_{X_\Gamma} \otimes [-q_1 -\cdots -q_r]$, where $q_i$ are cusps. But in the above equation, the $(\partial \bar{\partial} \log\log)$ term makes me confused to tell why the extension should be $T_{X_\Gamma} \otimes [-q_1 -\cdots -q_r]$. Also, my calculation shows that the cusp at infinity should have multiplicity $+1$ in the extension, not $-1$.

Or is there something wrong about my understanding on extending a line bundle using a singular Hermitian metric on an open Riemann surface to the compactified Riemann surface? My knowledge in the theory of current is very limited, and I think I should also read something further in this direction. I want to find a detailed reference focusing on application of currents on complex manifolds. I know there is a book by Pierre Lelong, but it is in French. Any other reference is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

Now I know the answer.

The volume form of the Poincare metric on $X(N)^0$ is integrable on the whole compactified curve $X(N)$, thus defies a closed positive current on $X(N)$ and has a cohomology class. We want to find a line bundle $\bar{L}$ on $X(N)$ such that its restriction to $X(N)^0$ is isomorphic to the $T(X(N)^0)$, and its first chern class is equal to $[\omega]\in H^1(X(N),\mathbb{C})$. A more general case is discussed at the beginning of the paper: Mumford, D. Hirzebruch's proportionality theorem in the non-compact case. Invent Math 42, 239–272 (1977).

The key is that after changing basis in a neighborhood of a cusp, say the cusp at infinity, the metric is written as $\frac{1}{\log |w|^2}$ and only has $\log$ singularity. This kind of singularity won't affect the cohomology class of the Chern form $c_1(T(X(N)^0),g)$ where $g$ is the Poincare metric on $X(N)^0$. The desired $\bar{L}$ in this case is $T(X(N))\otimes [\delta]^{-1}$ where $\delta$ is the effective divisor on $X(N)$ consisting of all cusps with coefficient one.